# Which is the default input method in application in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10?

Tags: gnome, input-method

Ok, this more than a question is a plea to explain this thing... I was trying to answer another question and I got tangled in a mess. Disclaimer: I am an old-time Unix/Linux user, maybe the technology has overtaken me...

I have a standard 13.10 installation with two input method: normal US and US with international dead-key (this last one is the default - I normally write in Spanish, Italian, and English, often mixed). I haven't selected any input method, so I'm using the default input method... which I'm at a loss to understand which is.

So. I create the file `.XCompose` with the following content (don't ask):

```
include "%L"

<dead_acute> <z> : "å" aring
<dead_acute> <Z> : "Å" Aring
```

And restart the server. Now `xterm`, `xjed`, `kile`  let me write the angstrom unit "Å" with the dead accent and then Z, while `gedit`, `gnome-terminal` still give "Ź".

I (think I) know how to modify the behavior via GTK_IM_MODULE (and co.) environment variables, but my question is oriented to trying to understand which is the default configuration --- what and where I have to change to have a consistent behavior across all applications.

I know, another question that will earn me another Tumbleweed badge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The ComposeKey sequences used by Gnome to enter special characters are hard coded into the program`, so your modified settings will work with X programs, and apparently KDE programs, but not with Gtk programs.

Source: [GtkComposeTable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable), which lists the Gnome compose key table. Gnome dead key settings are given at [GtkDeadKeyTable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkDeadKeyTable)

More information about using the compose key - and using `xim` to bypass the Gnome hardcodings - is given at [ComposeKey](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) in the community documentation.

> The Gnome hard coding can be overruled in favour of the original Xwindow Input Method (XIM) by setting the environment variable GTK_IM_MODULE. This can be set in the /etc/environment file, but if the machine has more than one user then it is best set from the home directory on a per user basis by modifying ~/.gnomerc or ~/.Xsession

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```

For `gnome-terminal`, right click in the terminal window, and in the context menu choose *Input methods >> X Input Method*

`xim` should be the default input method, but to make sure the default input method is being applied system wide, from *System Settings >> Language Support* make sure *Keyboard input method system* is set to `default`. This should make it so you don't need to right click the terminal window every time, but you will probably still need `GTK_IM_MODULE` environment setting.

Comment: Thanks... maybe I am starting to understand. SO, the default input method is `xim`, but Gtk applications override that in an hardcoded way (which, by the way, changed lately, given that <dead_acute>c used to give ç, now it's ć.)

Comment: Moreover, in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey they say that you could override that by using `GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" application`. That works like a charm for `gedit`but not for `gnome-terminal`... color me (still) confused.

Comment: @rmano Moved the info from the comments into the answer and added a little bit more. I apologize, I had meant to link to the full compose key page but left it out.